# Cloudwatch custom event is not triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

When i create the ec2 instance the cloud watch event should trigger, But it is not working.. Below is the event Json. Could you please help.

The same event is triggered successful in other aws account, I not sure what is wrong with this account. IAM policy to lambda has complete access and when i test lambda code it is working fine.. But the problem is the event should be triggered.

```
  {
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com",
      "rds.amazonaws.com",
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateVolume",
      "RunInstances",
      "RequestSpotInstances",
      "CreateSnapshot",
      "CreateVpnGateway",
      "CreateSecurityGroup",
      "CreateInternetGateway",
      "CreateNatGateway",
      "CreateVpc",
      "CreateSubnet",
      "CreateRouteTable",
      "CreateCustomerGateway",
      "CreateNetworkAcl",
      "CreateVpnConnection",
      "CreateImage",
      "CreateDBInstance",
      "CreateDBSnapshot",
      "CreateDBCluster",
      "CreateDBClusterParameterGroup",
      "CreateDBClusterSnapshot",
      "CreateDBInstanceReadReplica",
      "CreateDBParameterGroup",
      "CreateDBSecurityGroup",
      "CreateDBSubnetGroup",
      "CreateEventSubscription",
      "CreateOptionGroup",
      "CreateBucket"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you configuring **Trails** from **AWS CloudTrail** to track API Calls?

1) Check on your Trails configuration if the **Logging** status is *enabled* or not.

[image]

2) Check again on your policies as most of the cases, we mis-configured our **IAM policies** so one of the services cannot work as expected.

Comment: I am not using trails from Cloud trail, My event source is ec2.amazonaws.com not cloudtrail.amazonaws.com. and yes i verified the policy it already has admin role. since the event is not triggered the lambda has not initiated.. to trigger event.. i think we dont need to create and policy right?

Comment: Any API calls are being monitored by AWS CloudTrail. If not, you are not able to trigger your resources. Even from your code above, there is a line: 
"detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail" ].
Can you check on your "working" account if you are using Trails or not?

Comment: I have added this to the rule and stopped one of my instance, the rule was triggered. I havent made any setting change in my account.. if Cloudtrail is restricting my access.. this should have failed also..That was description, which i have written i can edit it to anything.. i just followed standard aws one
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ]
}

Comment: i got the problem, I need to enable the cloudwatch to the trail which i created.. that solved my problem.. thank you for the help and direction..thumps up man.

Comment: Great! glad to hear that you have solved it. Nice day :D